# Mesh function seems to swap x and y values

Tags: matlab, mesh

I am trying to plot a very simple function in the 3d plane.

```
f=zeros(101,101);
xs=0:0.1:10;
ys=0:0.1:10;

for j=1:101
    f(1,j)=ys(j);
end
```

Here are 3 plots:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The first is a plot of f vs x at ymin:

```
figure; plot(xs,f(:,1),'*r')
xlabel('x')
ylabel('f')
```

The second is a plot of f vs y at xmin:

```
figure; plot(ys,f(1,:),'*r')
xlabel('y')
ylabel('f')
```

And finally the third is a 3d mesh:

```
figure; mesh(xs,ys,f)
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
```

However the mesh plot seems to contradict the 2 2d plots, it seems to have the x and y switched around if you get me. Can anyone help? Should it be mesh(ys,xs,f) for some reason? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mesh` didn't switch your `x` and `y`, it's a matter of definition. Don't forget that a matrix doesn't have an `x` axis or a `y` axis but rather a row dimension and a column dimension. The row dimension is normally stated first in a pair just like the `x` dimension but if you are equating it too an image then you would normally have the `x` axis going across which is actually along the column axis!

Try like this rather

```
for j=1:101
    f(j,1)=ys(j);
end

figure; plot(xs,f(1,:),'*r')
xlabel('x')
ylabel('f')

figure; plot(ys,f(:,1),'*r')
xlabel('y')
ylabel('f')

figure; mesh(xs,ys,f)
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
```